# VB.net: Charting real-time price data using chart control

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to design a vb .net winforms software to chart real-time stock price data to chart control.
The price data is coming every 1 min via API.
I am wondering what a good system-level design for this problem.

How should I handle and store the incoming data and pass it to the chart control?
I would like to store the data and plot it in real-time on the chart.

Do I need some kind of queue or save the data in text file, or... ?

Curious about the design before I start coding.

Thank you.

Comment: Try DataSets. These links can help you. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/building-your-first-dataset-in-visual-basic-net.html http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you only need to update the Series inside the Chart control. For every few minutes, you update your chart using:

```
Chart1.Series("StockPrice").Points.addXY(currentTime, currentValue)
```

You can also make the curve moving by changeing the AxisX properties.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly needs to be changed from AxisX?